# Modeling Table Relationships using JPA in Java EE

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, jpa, glassfish

I have two 3 tables in my database:

```
group
----------
groupId    PK
name
```

```
user_account
----------
userId        PK
```

```
user_grouping
----------
groupId     PK    FK grouping(groupId -> groupId)
userId      PK    FK user_account(userId -> userId)
```

In my UserAccount Entity, I have the following line:

```
@JoinTable(name = "user_group", joinColumns = {
    @JoinColumn(name = "userId", referencedColumnName = "userId")}, inverseJoinColumns = {
    @JoinColumn(name = "groupId", referencedColumnName = "groupId")})
@ManyToMany
private List<Grouping> groupingList;
```

This is to show the relationship between all the tables. However, when I deploy, I get the following error:

```
SEVERE: Exception while preparing the app : Exception [EclipseLink-28018] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.3.2.v20111125-r10461): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.EntityManagerSetupException
Exception Description: Predeployment of PersistenceUnit [com.dv_model_ejb_1.0-SNAPSHOTPU] failed.
Internal Exception: Exception [EclipseLink-7220] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.3.2.v20111125-r10461): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.ValidationException
Exception Description: The @JoinColumns on the annotated element [field groupingList] from the entity class [class com.dv.model.entity.UserAccount] is incomplete. When the source entity class uses a composite primary key, a @JoinColumn must be specified for each join column using the @JoinColumns. Both the name and the referencedColumnName elements must be specified in each such @JoinColumn.
Local Exception Stack: 
Exception [EclipseLink-28018] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.3.2.v20111125-r10461): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.EntityManagerSetupException
Exception Description: Predeployment of PersistenceUnit [com.dv_model_ejb_1.0-SNAPSHOTPU] failed.
Internal Exception: Exception [EclipseLink-7220] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.3.2.v20111125-r10461): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.ValidationException
Exception Description: The @JoinColumns on the annotated element [field groupingList] from the entity class [class com.dv.model.entity.UserAccount] is incomplete. When the source entity class uses a composite primary key, a @JoinColumn must be specified for each join column using the @JoinColumns. Both the name and the referencedColumnName elements must be specified in each such @JoinColumn.
    at org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.EntityManagerSetupException.predeployFailed(EntityManagerSetupException.java:221)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.EntityManagerSetupImpl.predeploy(EntityManagerSetupImpl.java:1402)
...
```

I am not sure exactly how to interpret this error message. I am assuming I do not have the table relationship correctly modeled in my entity. But I am not sure why. Before today, this was compiling fine. Can anyone provide assistance?

Comment: Your code is not consistent. Is it user_group or user_grouping? And what is the Grouping entity? A Group? What's the mapping of both entities involved?

Answer (score 0):

Description of tables is inconsistent (grouping vs group) and name of join table in entity mappings is not one of the table names. Because of these
inconsistencies I assume following table structure:

```
useraccount (userid PK)
grouping (groupdid PK, name)
user_grouping (userId PK, groupId PK)
- FK userId references to user_account.userid
- FK groupId references to grouping.groupId
```

One correct way to map this to two entities is following:

```
@Entity
public class UserAccount {
    @Id int userId;

    @JoinTable(name = "user_grouping", joinColumns = {
       @JoinColumn(name = "userId", referencedColumnName = "userId")},
       inverseJoinColumns = {
       @JoinColumn(name = "groupId", referencedColumnName = "groupId")})
       @ManyToMany
       private List<Grouping> groupingList;
    //get and set omitted.
}

@Entity
public class Grouping {
    @Id int groupId;
    String name;
    //get,set, and optional inverse side of relationship omitted
}
```

Comment: You are correct in your assumption of the table structure. I messed some of the names up when I was trying to make it a simpler example. The only thing though, what you have for the UserAccount Entity is exactly what I have about in my description of the problem. It is what is giving me the issue.

Comment: That's odd, I just tested it with EclipseLink 2.3.2 and it works for me without problems. You can maybe edit your question to contain all mappings (including possible inverse side of relation) for further debugging.